# how to alter permalink in wordpress?

Tags: permalinks

I have created a wordpress page and url is `/demo-abcde`  and after saving I need to change it to `/demo`
But unable to find a way to edit the link and change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change using following steps:

Edit that post and find **Permalink** just after **Title**

click on **Edit** button

After Edit slug click on **Ok** and then **Update** post

Hope it will help!